# Error loading forms with PowerPacks items inside

Tags: vb.net, powerpacks

I have an old application WindowsForms with some PowerPacks items inside it.
I don't remember the version of VisualStudio i used to build it, but now, with version 17.8.3, this app doesn't work with error:
"Impossible to load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.9.0, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a or one of relative dipendencies. Impossible to find the specified file"
The version of PowerPacks i actually use is 12.0.0
The strange is that i use without errors the DataRepeater tool that is in this version of PowerPacks, but when i try to use the Rectangle Shape or other tools i receive the same error message written above.
Does anybody faced this error?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with my application, and I found that installing Visual Studio 2019 resolved the problem effectively. This version of Visual Studio allows for the installation and support of older .NET Framework versions, which is particularly beneficial for legacy applications. By moving to Visual Studio 2019, you should be able to maintain compatibility with the necessary components of your application, including those that rely on earlier versions of the .NET Framework. This approach worked well for me and might be the solution you're looking for as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you think that i can install 2 versions of VisualStudio in the same PC?

Comment: yes don't worry about that

Comment: The drawing tools (squire, triangle) does work for me in vs2022. However, do keep in min that vs2022 is the FIRST version of VS that is x64 bits. prior to 2022, VS was a x32 bit application. As a result, there is "some" higher degree of compatibility in vs2019 over vs2022 when working with older legacy code. However, as noted, you can install and have both vs2019, and vs2022 on your computer.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, nice to hear that in your VS2022 the square works! Did you install some other packages related to PowerPacks with VS2022?